# How can I add size parameters in an uiOutput element for a R "shiny" application?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing an R "shiny" application where it is necessary to pass size parameters (width and height) different to the corresponding defaults, for a leaflet map, for avoiding issues with a relatively large legend. The documentation for [leaflet](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/leaflet/html/leaflet.html) R package pointed out that these parameters could be set directly in the leaflet constructor, however, there are ignored in a shiny application.

For a 'leafletOutput' shiny method, following syntax, `leafletOutput("leaflet1", width = 200, height = 200)`, works properly. However, I need such parameters in a 'uiOutput' object where the following syntax `uiOutput("leaflet2", width = 200, height = 200)` doesn't produce any error but it doesn't work as expected.

So, I looked at UI Output [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/renderui) and I tried out this one approach `uiOutput("leaflet2", quoted = TRUE, outputArgs = list(width = 200, height = 200))` without any success. My question is how can I add size parameters in an uiOutput element for a shiny application?

My sample code looks as follows (original is too large):

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
         titlePanel(""),
         mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("leaflet1", width = 200, height = 200),               
            uiOutput("leaflet2", quoted = TRUE, outputArgs = list(width = 200, height = 200))
            )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$leaflet1 <- renderLeaflet({
        m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
        m
    })
    
    output$leaflet2 <- renderUI({
        output$leafletMap <- renderLeaflet({
            m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
            m
            })
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The result looks as follows when above code is run. As it can be observed, in the second render UI object the size parameters are completely ignored.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an RStudio question. I'll edit the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713809/how-to-dynamically-change-the-size-of-leaflet-map-in-shiny-r), I finally found out my answer. This is expressed in following code.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        
        titlePanel(""),
        
        mainPanel(
            
            leafletOutput("leaflet1", width = 200, height = 200),
           
            uiOutput("leaflet2")
            
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$leaflet1 <- renderLeaflet({
    
        m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
        
        m
        
    })
    

        
    output$leafletMap <- renderLeaflet({
            
            
            m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
            
            m
                        
    })
    
    
    output$leaflet2 <- renderUI({
        
        leafletOutput('leafletMap', width = 200, height = 200)
        
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

After running above code in **RStudio**, I got the desired result expressed in following image:

[image]

**Updating Note:**

After finding out the answer to this question, I faced a new issue relative to the following error message:

```
Can't access reactive value outside of reactive consumer
```

Above message was produced when I selected for displaying separately each one of these maps by using a Radio Button selector widget. I solved it when I added to above code a reactive **observe** statement.

Modified code looks as follows.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        
        sidebarPanel(
            
            titlePanel(""),
            
            radioButtons("maps", label = h3("Map options"),
                         choices = list("map1" = 1, "map2" = 2), 
                         selected = 1)
            
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            
            uiOutput("leaflet")
            
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$leafletMap1 <- renderLeaflet({
    
        m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lng = -111.71, lat = 40.13, zoom = 14)
        
        m
        
    })
    
    
    output$leafletMap2 <- renderLeaflet({
        
        url = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"    
    
        m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles(url) %>% setView(lng = -111.71, lat = 40.13, zoom = 14)
            
        m
                        
    })
    
    
    observe({     
        
        if (input$maps == 1) {
        
            output$leaflet <- renderUI({
                
                leafletOutput('leafletMap1', width = "100%", height = 400)
                
            })
        
        }
        
        if (input$maps == 2) {
        
            output$leaflet <- renderUI({
                
                leafletOutput('leafletMap2', width = "100%", height = 400)
                
            })
        }
    
    })
    
    


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Result, with option one (map1) is:

[image]

and with option 2 (map2) is:

[image]

It worked as expected; inclusively in my extended code which was successfully loaded in **shinyapps.io**.